# GZIP (using .htaccess) compression working on localhost but not on server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I'm new to GZip compression and am trying to speed up my webpage performance.

On `localhost`, I simply added this code to my `.htaccess`, and it works fine:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

However, when hosting it online (you can see it at [The Homework Life](http://thehomeworklife.co.nf/)), it says G-Zip compression is not enabled. This is a screenshot from Chrome's auditing (which doesn't appear on `localhost`):

[image: chrome_snapshot]

Is this because my hosting is not allowing it? (It's [Biz.nf](http://www.biz.nf), and it's a free hosting.) If so, what can I do to circumvent this (I've heard you can use PHP to gzip, but only with those PHP files, not other resources)? Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If that module is not installed you could try to handle it yourself with `gzipIt.php`:

```php
<?php
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
readfile($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
?>
```

Here the rules for the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ".(html?|txt|css|js)$" "gzipIt.php"
```

This will redirect all files with your endings (except scripts) and pushed it through the script above which takes the url from the redirection and read the file from the hard drive and gzip it out.